# Trying to make a massive series of API requests, but getting malformed JSON due to number of requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch some data in Node.JS from a service used to house employee data. After getting an access token, I have a function that the token is passed to along with an array of employee IDs (1500+). When I run the code with 2-3 hardcoded IDs it works perfectly fine. When I pass it the full array I start getting the following types of errors.

This one fires an untold number of times.

```
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://comp.site.com/service/odatav4/public/user/user-service/v1/dataset?$filter=criteria/targetUserID%20eq%20%27123%27 reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
    ...
  type: 'invalid-json'
```

Before ending with the following error.

```
D:\data-fetch-test\index.js:96
        const values = ID.data.value
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

I'll include an abbreviated example of the problem section below.

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const getAllOrgData = async (accessToken, empIDs) => {
  const fetchOrgData = async emp => {
    const orgDataHeaderContent = [
      ['Content-Type', 'application/json'],
      ['Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`]
    ]
    const orgDataHeaders = new fetch.Headers(orgDataHeaderContent)
    const orgDataOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: orgDataHeaders
    }
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://comp.site.com/service/odatav4/public/user/user-service/v1/dataset?$filter=criteria/targetUserID eq '${emp}'`,
      orgDataOptions
    )
    const empOrgData = await response.json().catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
    return empOrgData
  }
  const allOrgData = async () => {
    const OrgData = await empIDs.map(async ID => ({
      id: ID,
      data: await fetchOrgData(ID)
    }))
    return await Promise.all(OrgData)
  }
  return await allOrgData()
}

;(async function () {
  const headcountPath = String.raw`\\local\network\path\Headcount.csv`
  const empIDs = await getHeadcountData(headcountPath)
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken()
  const allOrgData = await getAllOrgData(accessToken, empIDs)
    .then(data =>
      data.map(ID => {
        const id = ID.id
        const values = ID.data.value
        return values.map(record => ({ ...record, AMEI: id }))
      })
    )
    .then(data => {
      const flatData = data.flat()
      generateCSV(flatData)
    })
})()
```

I'm totally at a loss of what to do next.

Comment: Sounds like your endpoint has race conditions. You can not do anything on the client side to properly address that if that's the problem. You can "help" your client be slightly more reliable by making the request one at a time instead of all in parallel if you have no power over the endpoint.

Comment: If you throw in a check for `response.status` before calling `response.json()`, are you getting rate limited (429 status)?

Comment: You need to see if the service has any limits on it's response size. If the characters stop part way the JSON will not be valid. You can inspect the response (run the same in cURL to see what comes back). Or check maybe split the request into smaller chunks of user ids.

Comment: I'm getting a 503 error. I think I need to rewrite this to call smaller chunks of IDs at a time, or maybe one at a time. The only problem is that my token is only good for 30 minutes, and I have no idea how to handle the added complexity of getting a new token after 30 minutes (if it comes to that) and then resuming the API calls where it left off.

Comment: If I have one user that's response comes in two parts due to size, I'm also not sure how to handle that. I'm assuming I could get the text response instead of the JSON and then join it all together at the end.